# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, mysql, jar, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use MySQL (phpmyadmin) in my android 2.1 update 1 version. I downloaded the driver of MySQL and included the jar file to my referenced library. From then, I'm having error

`Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

I saw couple of solutions but everyone is saying to remove the .jar files which I can't. I need both `jama-1.0.2.jar` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar`.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that mysql supports Android. Also android has his own database engine which is called SQLite.

PHPMyAdmin is a php project that gives a UI on a mysql server/connection. To run it you need a webserver and php, both do not support android, afaik.